# left_join with individual lag to new column

Tags: r, left-join

I need to merge two data frames probably with `left_join`, offset the joining observation by a specific amount and add it to a new column. The purpose is the preparation of a time-series analysis hence the different shifts in calendar weeks. I would like to stay in the tidyverse.

I read a few posts with a nested `left-join()` and `lag()` but that's beyond my current capability.

**MWE**

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Week1 = sample(paste("2015", 20:40, sep = "."),10, replace = FALSE),
  Qty = as.numeric(sample(1:10)))

df2 <- data.frame(
  Week2 = paste0("2015.", 1:52),
  Value = as.numeric(sample(1:52)))

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Week1" = "Week2")) %>%
  rename(Lag_0 = Value)
```

**Current output**

```
+----+---------+-------+-------+
|    | Week1   | Qty   | Lag_0 |
+====+=========+=======+=======+
| 1  | 2015.35 | 6.00  | 50.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 2  | 2015.24 | 10.00 | 26.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 3  | 2015.31 | 7.00  | 43.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 4  | 2015.34 | 9.00  | 42.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 5  | 2015.28 | 4.00  | 10.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 6  | 2015.39 | 8.00  | 24.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 7  | 2015.25 | 5.00  | 33.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 8  | 2015.23 | 1.00  | 39.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 9  | 2015.21 | 2.00  | 17.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| 10 | 2015.26 | 3.00  | 27.00 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
```

It might be worthwhile pointing out that the target data frame does not hold the same amount of week observations as the joining data frame.

**Desired output**

```
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|    | Week1   | Qty   | Lag_0 | Lag_3 | Lag_6 | Lag_12 |
+====+=========+=======+=======+=======+=======+========+
| 1  | 2015.35 | 6.00  | 50.00 | 9.00  |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 2  | 2015.24 | 10.00 | 26.00 | 17.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 3  | 2015.31 | 7.00  | 43.00 | 10.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 4  | 2015.34 | 9.00  | 42.00 | 43.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 5  | 2015.28 | 4.00  | 10.00 | 33.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 6  | 2015.39 | 8.00  | 24.00 | 13.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 7  | 2015.25 | 5.00  | 33.00 | 25.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 8  | 2015.23 | 1.00  | 39.00 | 38.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 9  | 2015.21 | 2.00  | 17.00 | 6.00  |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 10 | 2015.26 | 3.00  | 27.00 | 39.00 |       |        |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Column `Lag_3`, which I added manually, contains the values from the matching `df2` week value but offset by three rows. `Lag_6` would be offset by six rows, etc.
I suppose the challenge is, that the `lag()` would have to happen in the joining table after the matching but before the returning of the value.

Hope this makes sense and thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to create the `lag` before in the second data and then do the join

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    mutate(Lag_3 = lag(Value, 3), Lag_6 = lag(Value, 6)) %>% 
    left_join(df1, ., by = c("Week1" = "Week2")) %>%
    rename(Lag_0 = Value)
```

-output

```
#     Week1 Qty Lag_0 Lag_3 Lag_6
#1  2015.35   6    50     9    46
#2  2015.24  10    26    17     6
#3  2015.31   7    43    10    33
#4  2015.34   9    42    43    10
#5  2015.28   4    10    33    25
#6  2015.39   8    24    13    16
#7  2015.25   5    33    25    49
#8  2015.23   1    39    38    15
#9  2015.21   2    17     6    32
#10 2015.26   3    27    39    38
```

Comment: It can be so obvious and so straightforward sometimes... Thanks again for your help @akrun

Comment: @Max If you are okay to use `data.table`, then this is much more easier as, `shift` can take multiple `n`

Comment: I will certainly look into this. For the moment, I am trying to familiarise myself with the tidy packages to get done what I need to for my thesis. Thanks for the suggestion though.